# Firebase facebook logout

Tags: firebase, facebook-authentication

I currently learning on firebase facebook auth but it seems like firebase doesn't provide facebook logout api?

Because I logout at firefeed.io but it doesn't logout facebook itself.
and i also cannot find and logout() api in documents

So how can we logout both firebase and facebook ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way for 3rd party apps to log users in / out of Facebook itself (at least that I'm aware of).

You can log the app out with the logout() command of the Simple Login library:
https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/simple-login-overview.html